# How to align a div around bootstrap form-inline

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m using Bootstrap 3 "form-inline" within a `<div>`.
Somehow the div is "folded within" the form-inline.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
        <div class="form-inline">    
            <div class="row"> 
                <label>Name:</label>   
                <div class="form-group inner-addon right-addon  pull-right">
                    <i style="font-size: 10px; padding: 8px 6px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: nameFilter, stopBubble:true" placeholder="<name>" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">    
            <div class="row"> 
                <label>Name2:</label>   
                <div class="form-group inner-addon right-addon pull-right">
                    <i style="font-size: 10px; padding: 8px 6px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: nameFilter, stopBubble:true" placeholder="<name>" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    float: left;
}
.inner-addon { 
    position: relative; 
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.right-addon .glyphicon{ 
    right: 0px;
}
```

Where do I go wrong?

[Bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/Cunrsro7wL)

I have added some more rows and a pull-right to this to show what I want. Sorry about that lacking in the original question.

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle to show the problem?

Comment: Also form-inline shouldn't have a row inside of it, instead it should be form-group inside check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline for more details

Comment: so you want mame and input box in one row?

Comment: Doubly also, you shouldn't use "JSFiddle" to work with bootstrap problems.  Go to (http://www.bootply.com) Here, I put a link to your code posted there for your convenience here: (http://www.bootply.com/28TWtVtbSb)

Comment: Yep my mistake @MikeHorstmann

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap you shouldn't place a row inside the form-inline, simply remove this and a couple of little changes and this now works perfect.

See [Example Here](http://www.bootply.com/OFN7u3MdE9#)

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="form-inline">    
        <label>Mame:</label>   
        <div class="form-group inner-addon right-addon">
           <i style="font-size: 10px; padding: 8px 6px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
           <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: nameFilter, stopBubble:true" placeholder="<name>" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Examples of all Bootstrap properties can be found on there [website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) which is very helpful

Comment: Hi @hjardine! This is close to what I wanted. I see now my question was somehow lacking a dimension as I want several lines with the input-form aligned to the right. This is what I have got currently: http://www.bootply.com/Cunrsro7wL

Comment: Hi @AsleG if you want multiple lines why don't you use a horizontal form? check here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal Then pull that right?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">

    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="row">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <div class="form-group inner-addon right-addon">
          <i style="font-size: 10px; padding: 8px 6px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="textInput: nameFilter, stopBubble:true" placeholder="<name>" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/15006/)